# C# structural highlighting in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, highlighting, visual-studio-addins

Is there any way to make code blocks highlighting/collapsing in Resharper ?
In CodeRush it is called "structural highlighting" feature: 
[image]

 
Or maybe other Visual Studio 2010 add-on(preferably free) which would do this simple job and would not conflict with Resharper.

thanks

Comment: Wow, the amount of visual noise is disturbing. I find it harder to read the code with all those mutlicolored lines. I think I'll stick with indentation to give me the needed visual ques. But to each his own.

Comment: It is very useful especially if your intends are 2 instead of 4 and you don't place opening brace on new line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think that Resharper have this feature, instead you could use the free Visual Studio 2010 extension : [StructureAdornment](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/203f22f4-3e9f-4dbb-befc-f2606835834e)

[image: StructureAdornment screenshot]

Comment: oo I'm looking for that, any idea if there is something similar for VB on VS2005 ?

Comment: I've downloaded this StructureAdornment addon few months ago, and I like it very much. However, it disappeared from the Visual Studio Gallery few days later and is not available anymore. That is shame.

Answer (score 2):

ReSharper itself can not do this for you out of the box but you could use the free [CodeRush Xpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/) wich is compatible with ReSharper.

Comment: I don't think devExpress do code rush xpress any more, that link certainly doesn't work any more. Nor do any of the other links I've found

Comment: Same here; looks like they have completely wiped it from the net to force people onto the paid version. I don't have the money for both ReSharper and CodeRush at about $25 per month each...